# XeLaTeX / TeX compiling after Yosemite

Tags: macos, latex, tex, xelatex

I've been trying to compile LaTeX documents through the TexWorks front end. I arrive at this error even after completely removing and reinstalling all of the MacTeX package:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 180.

<black_bus.eps> <black_bus.eps> [1] (./4FE3 Assignment 1.toc)
(./4FE3 Assignment 1.lof) <black_bus.eps> [2sh: xdvipdfmx: command not found
] <black_bus.eps> [3]
<black_bus.eps> [4
Process crashed
```

Any ideas? I've tried compiling other documents to no avail

I'm not too familiar with Terminal usage and would appreciate any and all guidance

EDIT: Solution found here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208310

Comment: How has TexWorks set-up it's/your path? Seems the same question as on [tex stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208544/xelatex-in-texworks-cant-find-xdvipdfmx-crashes).

Comment: >How has TexWorks set-up it's/your path? Seems the same question as on tex stackexchange. –  Timothy Brown 5 mins ago
Hi Timothy. Thanks a lot you've saved me a lot of time! The solution is below which I have found to work for me..

http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208310